# Delphi: How to embed a VCL form into a panel

Tags: user-interface, delphi, embed, vcl

The form "Form1" contains a panel.

On this panel we want to embed a second form "Form2".

But not only the components should be embedded, but also the functionality.

I am using a VCL form.

I have already tried this tutorial on this page.

[How to put a form in panel](http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?p=37440)

```
unit parent;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls, child;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2 := TForm2.Create(Panel1);
  with Form2 do
    Name := 'MyForm';
    Parent := Panel1;
    Width := 500;
    Height := 500;
    Top := 10;
    Left := 10;
    Show;
end;

end.
```

```
unit child;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    btnCalc: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Edit3: TEdit;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure btnCalcClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.btnCalcClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  edit3.Text:=edit1.Text+edit2.Text;
end;

end.
```

The form is not displayed at startup and Form2 is not embedded in Form1.

Comment: Take a closer look at what you have written in `procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);`.

Comment: _we want to embed a second form "Form2"_ So why you are using `TForm1`?

Comment: @Sami  I have edit my code now. But form2 is still not in panel of form1. What  have i done wrong?

Comment: @TomBrunberg see my comment above

Comment: Why are you embedding a `TForm` instead of using a `TFrame`? `TForm` is intended to be a free-floating window, it was never intended to be embedded. `TFrame` is specifically designed for embedding.

Comment: Functionally they cannot be equivalent as one is a top-level window.

Comment: You are missing the begin/end pair after the with clause.

Comment: @RemyLebeau TFrame doesn't have all the events that a TForm has, like OnCreate/OnDestroy, OnShow, etc, so I can see why people would want to use it. Also, it may be that he is reusing another form and doesn't want to refactor it into a TFrame.

Comment: Uwe is correct but to add to what he said, you should avoid using with for exactly this reason.

Comment: The "with" cannot be the issue, that would lead to a circular parenting request which would cause a runtime error, not "form2 is not embedded"..Missing begin/end is just due to the sloppy question...

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, there is no description what is actually happening running the above code. It is quite possible that the error you describe is shown.

Comment: Well, I can't imagine a  runtime error being described as "the form is not embedded", but as sloppy the question is, that is also possible.

Answer (score 4):

For future reference, when you post a question about code, copy - paste **actual code** and **inform possible shown errors**.

In the first edition of your question, your code recreated `Form1` within the constructor of the same form. After some time the program fails with an out of resources error.

In your second edition, where you corrected erroneous references of `Form1` to `Form2` your code is still missing a `begin .. end` pair around the properties you want to set after `with Form2 do`. This error leads to a stack overflow because you are setting `Form1` parent to `Panel1` which is a child of `Form1`, iow a chicken - egg dilemma.

Because you did not mention either of these errors, one can only conclude that your code is different from what you have posted, or, you think that error messages are not important. WRONG! So, please take the lesson and pay attention to **post actual code** and **inform about any error messages**.

Also, if your question is about appearance of a form, post the `.dfm` file content.

---

With the following code `Form2` is shown embedded in the `Panel1` of `Form1` (I removed the width and height settings to keep the image smaller):

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2 := TForm2.Create(Panel1);
  with Form2 do
  begin
    Name := 'MyForm';
    Parent := Panel1;
    Top := 10;
    Left := 10;
    Show;
  end;
end;
```

[image]

The `Top` and `Left` properties don't look as expected. That is because the default value of the `TForm.Position` property is `poDefaultPosOnly` which means that the form bypasses the `Top` and `Left` settings and leaves it to the OS to decide on the location. However since the form is given a parent that doesn't apply either and the form is just placed at position 0,0. Add the line regarding `position` property below (or set it in `Form2` designer).

```
...
Parent := Panel1;
Position := poDesigned; // add this line
BorderStyle := bsNone;  // and this for a better embedded appearance
Top := 10;
...
```

The result is now:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps setting `BorderStyle := bsNone;` could be of value here.

Comment: @Uwe After all, I followed your suggestion